# Organic groups automatic audience selection

Tags: organic-groups

I am working with organic groups. Within each group, permitted users are allowed to create their own pages.

**What my problem is that I need to set the audience for a new page automatically as the group the user is currently in.**
This is so that the user cannot manually change the group the post should go into but instead it's automatically and permanently set ( unless an administrator changes it ).

Does anyone know of a way that I might accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module to pass the group's gid to the node add form.
For example, the link will looks something like this:

```
node/add/discussion?edit[group_audience][und]=4
```

You could then hide the group selection box with css so the user cannot change it.
For a more robust solution you would code a form hook. Here is an [example](http://drupal.org/node/967640).

Comment: I implemented hook_form_alter to set access to false for an element when not an administrator - before I read your solution. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of using a Rule and have gotten it to work using the following Rule config: Event=Before Saving Content, Condition=Content is of a Certain Type, Action: Entity=Node, Group=Site:Current-group - YES - works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I found this in my own search.

I'm new to this, but I think this is going to work for me.

NEW "RULE"

Event = Before Saving New Content --- Node/Content type
Action = Data/set data value/node:og-group-ref:0 (Groups Audience)

Answer (score -1):

With Drupal 7, you don't need the Prepopulate module.

You can just use this `node/add/blog?og_group_ref=1` where 1 is the group ID.