# Using OG and FormBlock I want FormBlock content to default to current group

Tags: 7, organic-groups

This question is somewhat similar to this one: [Organic groups automatic audience selection](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16151/organic-groups-automatic-audience-selection) - only I am using FormBlock module to create OG content from within the home page of the group.  I don't want the user to select which group they are posting into - I want it to default to the current group context.

Another layer of complexity is that I'm using QuickTabs - each tab has a different formblock.  So I am not making a call to the node/add form.  I simply want the current OG context to default as the new content's audience.

Anyone have any ideas?

I like the idea of using a Rule and have tried but can't seem to get the rule to accept a proper data selector using: Event=Before Saving Content, Condition=Content is of a Certain Type, - the Action is what is tripping me up.  I'm trying to use the Action of OG - Add Entity to Group.

Comment: I just figured this out - I had to use the following Action: Entity=Node, Group=Site:Current-group - YES - works like a charm!