# Pre-select Group Audience for Organic Groups

Tags: users, organic-groups

Here is my situation.

I am using the latest version of Organic Groups on Drupal 7. Every user on my site is part of one group and one group only. Is there a way to make it so that when users are creating group content, the group they belong to is automatically pre-selected? Again, every user is only in one group (but there are numerous groups), so it's superfluous to force them to make a group selection whenever they are creating group content.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Field Permission module to not allow a user to see the group field on content type.
2. Use  [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7) to set a default field value for group field based on current logged in user.

as a sample code (not tested)

```
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $node = $form_state['node'];
  if (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) {
    global $user;
    $groups = og_get_groups_by_user($user);
      if(is_array($groups)) {
      // This needs to be evaluated to check proper mapping of what field expect to set a default default field value
      $form['group_field_name']['#default'] = $groups[0];  
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm, but right now, when creating the content type, the group options are None and whatever group the user is in. If I just hid the field using Field Permission, the user's group wouldn't end up getting selected...

Comment: for now do not hide the field, keep it there till you fix second step to make, once you make sure you are able to set the default group then hide the field. If you are not finding the codes mentioned in second point, there is an alternate approach http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16151/organic-groups-automatic-audience-selection

Comment: if I went with your code approach, where would I put it?

Answer (score 0):

[Entity Reference Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate) is the best way to do this without custom code like arpitr described. You would rewrite the links to look like

```
/node/add/article?og_group_ref=123
```

These links could be on the group's page or you may find a token to populate the gid automatically based on user.